# Double DESC with Double LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a mysql SELECT which it select the last 20 ids and it shows the 7 with the biggest clicks but from the last 20 ids the 7 biggest clicks..and not from all ids I tried with DESC and LIMIT but its not working..any idea??

```
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY clicks DESC, id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 7
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 UNION SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Can you add a sample data and the desired result? If it is too much data consider in creating a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20
) SUB
ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 7
```

**EDIT:**

> What is SUB doing..?

*SUB* is the alias for the subquery `SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20`. It could have different names which is up to you.

```
SELECT * FROM /*<=== Query 2 - Will be executed after Query 1 is run, thus will perform a search within the results returned by Query1*/
(
    SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20 /*<=== SUBQUERY - Query 1 - Will be executed first */
) 
ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 7
```

What we're going here is that; first we get a result set of most recent 20 rows from `search` with `SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20` *SUB* and then we run a `SELECT` query **IN** the result set returned by *SUB*.

Comment: What SUB doing..? Best Question till now..but its not doing that I need its not selecting by id desc and click desc :/ Example: I have on id 96 10 clicks on id 95 20 clicks and on id 93 0 clicks..II made limit of id 3 and limit 2 and its shoing the 93 and 96..its must be like 95 first and 96 second..

Comment: see the updated answer for your questions regarding SUB. I'm not sure I fully understand your example though. can you elaborate? perhaps, update your question with sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Where ' 0 ' represent the starting position of your result and ' 20 ' represent the length of your result.